# Control order of AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Can I make an AJAX request in a Chrome extension to run only after all the other AJAX requests on the page have finished? I have a function that modifies the page elements, but it can only run properly after all other JS have run.

Right now, I am using `$(document).click(func);` to invoke my function, but I think that there would be a better way for this.

Comment: *"only after all the other AJAX requests on the page have finished"* - How can it predict whether the page might make another Ajax request later, perhaps in response to a user or timer event? (It can't.)

Comment: Are you controlling all the other AJAX calls?

Comment: @unobf, no, they are provided by the site.

Comment: Are there predictable elements that are getting created after the other AJAX requests?

Comment: @unobf, maybe some elements, classes, or ids would appear.

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes, a setTimeout or click event works, but I want it to run properly, timely, and automatically.

Comment: I wasn't saying you should use `setTimeout` or a click event, I was saying that there's no way for the code *you* write to predict whether the page is going to do further Ajax requests in the future in response to its own timeout or click or other events.

Answer (score 0):

If you can predict what elements are going to be inserted into the page, you could use the mutationObserver to watch for all the changes that you expect and then when all have occurred, run your code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Some code might look like this:

```
(function () {
    var expectedMutations = [...]; // put your expected mutations in here + some way to track if they have been seen

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        // if the mutation matches do something
      });
      if (all mutations matched) {
        // disconnect the observer
        observer.disconnect();
        // do AJAX call
      }
    });

    // configuration of the observer:
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(document.body, config);
}());
```

Note this does not work in older browsers, there are older mutation watching APIs if you need to support older browsers. Here is the list that support it

https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/wiki/DOMMutationObservers#Browser_Availability

And here is the older API based on event listeners

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Answer (score -1):

You may check out async.js to take control of your flow:
https://github.com/caolan/async

Or, if you are likely to implement something like yourself you can implement something like this:

```
var totalRequestCount = 10; // You may apply your own count here.
var executedRequestCount = 0;
```

And implement every callback method like this

```
var callback = function() {
  executedRequestCount ++;
  if (totalRequestsCount === executedRequestsCount) {
    // put the last request here
  }
};
```

P.S. I think there should be some other ways to optimize the life cycle of the entire page.

Comment: Not helpful as written: the requests happen in the page's code not controlled by the extension. For this to work, OP would need to inject code into the page to hijack whatever AJAX mechanism is being used.